# What exactly does this mean in Python?

Tags: python

I was working on a project Euler problem and found this code online:

```
a = 1
b = 2
s = 0

while b <= 4000000:
    if not b % 2:
        s += b
    a, b = b, a + b
print s
```

I am not entirely sure what `if not b % 2:` means and was wondering if someone would mind shedding some light on it for me.

Comment: `if not b % 2:` = if the remainder of b / 2 is 0.

Comment: Did you read the Python documentation for what "not" means and what the % operator does?

Comment: `%` in most modern programming languages means modulus/remaining. You should look for the language documentation before asking such basic questions

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations):

`The % (modulo) operator yields the remainder from the division of the first argument by the second.`

e.g. `5/2 == 2.5 # or 2 remainder 1`, `5%2 == 1`

The only time a `%` operation will come out to `0` (which satisfies `not x%y`) is if it's evenly divisible. In other words, `4 % 2 == 0` because 2 divides 4 evenly.

In your code, it's saying:

```
while b is less than 4,000,000:
    if b is even:
        set s equal to s+b
```

Answer (score 1):

The [modulo `%` operator](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations) returns the remainder of the division of `b` per 2 (in your case).
So `if not b % 2` is the same meaning that `if b % 2 == 0`: it checks if the number is even.

Answer (score 0):

`b % 2` is the remainder after dividing by 2.  So it will be 1 if b is odd, or 0 otherwise.

`if not b % 2` can thus be translated to "if b is even"

Answer (score 0):

Python interprets the value 1 as True and 0 as False:

```
>>> 1 == True
True
>>> 0 == True
False
```

The modulo operation `x % y` returns the remainder when `x` is divided by `y`. Therefore `b % 2` will be `0` when `b` is even, and `1` when `b` is odd.

Combining all this together, the statement `if not b % 2:` corresponds to "if b is even".

Comment: No, that is not correct.  In Python, every integer except for `0` evaluates to `True` in a boolean context.  The behavior that you are seeing can be explained by the fact that `True` evaluates to `1` when it is interpreted as an integer (this is for historical reasons).

Comment: Ah, I see. I'll edit my answer to remove the confusion.

Answer (score -1):

It's just a cute way of writing `if b%2==0`. The `not` operator when passed `0` will return `True`, and `False` given anything else.

Comment: Fun fact: since Python is memory efficient and only produces pointers for small integers, you can do `if b%2 is 0` and freak out every programmer who has to maintain your code!